# passing result  from jquery .sortable('serialize') in a post request

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, coffeescript

So I know that `$('#table_content').sortable('serialize')` returns an array because I tested it with console.info.  What I want to do is use the value of that expression as data in a post request but I want it's result to be passed as data in a callback to another ajax request.  I thought I could do this by just placing `$('#table_content').sortable('serialize')` as the data argument for .post but when I do this, the parameter is "undefined=undefined" according to firebug.

```
jQuery ->
  ids = $('#table_content').sortable('serialize')
  console.info(ids)

  $('#tasks_table').load('/dashboard #tasks_table', null, -> $.post('/tasks/sort', $('#table_content').sortable('serialize'), ->location.reload()))

undefined=undefined
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?  Note, that if I pass `ids` in the place of `$('#table_content').sortable('serialize')`, it works but I only want to the value of the `$('#table_content').sortable('serialize')` once the previous ajax request has run.  If I just use ids, then it's value does not reflect the change after calling `$('#tasks_table').load`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you example, it seems you end-up with the following structure after loading (maybe not a DIV element of course):

```
<!-- #tasks_table you call .load() upon -->
<div id="tasks_table"> 
   <!-- #tasks_table that is loaded -->
   <div id="tasks_table">
   </div>
</div>
```

Be aware that loading page fragments will **insert** the loaded fragment (including the wrapping element) **into** the matched set elements, not replace them !

You should probably extract the children of the #tasks_table in the load:

```
$('#tasks_table').load('/dashboard #tasks_table > *', ... );
```

---

Not sure about this one but you'll maybe have to **initialize** the sortable plugin before calling the 'serialize' method on the loaded content.

```
$('#tasks_table').load('/dashboard #tasks_table', null, function() {
    var ids = $('#table_content')
        .sortable() // init first
        .sortable('serialize'); // then call 'serialize'
    $.post('/tasks/sort', ids, function() {
        location.reload()
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I just needed to initialize my ids variable inside of the callback function.  That makes perfect sense.  It works great now except the location.reload() function reloads the page and the new data that changed after doing the post request is not displayed.  Instead I have to manually reload the page and only then are the changes reflected.  This seems a bit odd to me as I thought the callback function of the post request would only execute once the post request has been successfully made.  Any ideas on this one?

Comment: it is a success callback so it is called upon success. Are you sure of the data that is posted ? Are you sure of what you do with it server-side ? Also, why use ajax if you reload the whole page afterwards ?